# .Net DropDownList validation for subset of possible selections?

Tags: .net, validation

I have a DropDownList selection on a .Net web form that needs to be validated for specific selections based upon other actions on the form.  Specifically I need to validate depending upon CheckBox components.  I was looking at the [CompareValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db330ayw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but it doesn't appear to be possible without a lot of hacking.
Can I enable this requirement through a built-in or custom .Net validator or must I code the behavior through JavaScript or code-behinds?

Thanks much!

Comment: Have you looked at the [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx)?